# How to refresh text in a TextView programatically?

Tags: java, android

I have following timer:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        --mTimer;
        mTimeLeft.setText(String.valueOf(mTimer));
    }

}, 0, 1000);
```

Text in the `TextView` will change when I touch the screen.

How can I refresh the `TextView` programatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this article will help you. http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2007/11/stitch-in-time.html
Basically you want to use the `Handler` class provided in the SDK. You shouldn't need to call invalidate like someone else suggested because setText does that for you.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

The UI should be updated from the main thread. Take a look at [this example](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html) that is closer to what you want.

Comment: Didn't notice your post, I posted the same article. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
    TextView yourTextView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.your_text_view_ID);
    yourTextView.setText("your text");
```

Comment: To the @hovanessyan - this answer could be improved upon somewhat with a description as to why it's the solution; you're liable to be downvoted otherwise.  To the flaggers: stackoverflow.com/faq#etiquette states " If you see misinformation, **vote it down**. **Add comments** indicating what, specifically, is wrong. Provide better answers of your own. Best of all — **edit and improve the existing questions and answers!**"

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't change, try calling `invalidate`. Also, make sure you are calling from the UI thread, if not then use `post` method to send a runnable that will be executed in the UI thread (There you can change the text.)